# inserting only date in a column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to insert only date in a datetime column in sql server without the time?
for example

> date (datetime)
>
> ===============
>
> 12-01-2000
>
> 16-02-2000

or i should store this as a varchar and **cast** it when retriving so that i can convert to whatever form i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my solution is to store it as varchar and convert it to datetime whenever needed

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111) -- get datepart onl`y

or

also check this post about creating date type :

create user defined data types:

```
create type Date from dateTime
```

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/31/sql-server-2005-date-time-only-data-types.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure if order by would work correct, if you store in varchar format.

Comment: ya for that you have to convert it back in datetime its better to use second option create user defined type

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQLServer 2008 you can use the `date` data type.

The following SQL will strip out any time values and set them all to zero. So you won't need to worry whether a time value is there or not.

```
Select  Cast(Floor(Cast(MyDateColumn as float)) as DateTime) as MyDateColumn
From dbo.MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use ***smalldatetime*** or ***date***. Convert your dates to your format before you update your date values or after you select date values in your app.

You can change format of date format in sql queries or in your app.

Here is a list on date formats in sql

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Here's a link on date data types

http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/date_time.htm

Good Luck!