# How to remove the time?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, vb.net

So I was trying to retrieve the date only from the database but then it always comes with time, I don't know why but the data type of that field in my database is date. Now, how to retrieve the data with having date only.

Here my code:

```
            Dim strA As String = ddlSChedName.SelectedValue.ToString()
            sqlcon = New SqlConnection(conString)
            sqlcon.Open()
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.CS_refSched WHERE
            SchedID=" + strA + "", sqlcon)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(ds)
            dt = ds.Tables(0)
            sqlcon.Close()

            Dim a1 As String = dt.Rows(0)("From").ToString()
            Dim b As String = dt.Rows(0)("To").ToString()
            Dim c As String = dt.Rows(0)("SetID").ToString()
```

Comment: What is the structure of your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to convert the dates (WHich I'm assuming are "To" and "From") and output them as strings that include the date only

```
Dim strA As String = ddlSChedName.SelectedValue.ToString()
sqlcon = New SqlConnection(conString)
sqlcon.Open()
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.CS_refSched WHERE SchedID=" + strA + "", sqlcon)
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(ds)
dt = ds.Tables(0)
sqlcon.Close()

Dim a1 As String = cDate(dt.Rows(0)("From")).ToString("d")
Dim b As String = cDate(dt.Rows(0)("To")).ToString("d")
Dim c As String = dt.Rows(0)("SetID").ToString()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `DateTime.ToShortDateString()` which will honor your culture/locale.

Answer (score 0):

And you can also use this to retrieve

```
date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim a1 As String = cDate(dt.Rows(0)("From")).ToString("d").Substring(0,10)

Answer (score 0):

To store date only in the sql server 
create your own datatype

```
create type Date from dateTime
```

[inserting only date in a column in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910524/inserting-only-date-in-a-column-in-sql-server)